# Escaping user inputs to prevent issues with code

Tags: javascript

I have some user provided variable that gets inserted into a script. Normally this works well, but fails when certain characters such as quotes are used. Is there a way to escape this?

```
document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = "<div oncontextmenu='javascript:alert(" + var1 + ");return false;'>" + var2 + "</div>";
```

Comment: Have your server do the escaping, not javascript?

Comment: I was trying that approach initially, but was getting issues with things like links not working. Is server escaping the best way of doing this? Also, if using server escaping I was going to use PHP's htmlentities. Theres different flags, such as ENT_QUOTES and ENT_HTML5. What type of escaping should I do for JS?

Comment: It's too hard to know, without knowing more of your use case. If the you are taking a user's input and running a script that only they will be "affected" by, then you could do escaping in javascript. But if you are taking user 1's input and affecting user 2 with it, then you have many many security concerns that you need to carefully consider. I can't answer what "type" of escaping you should do unless I knew a lot more

Answer (score 1):

Try using:

```
document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = `<div oncontextmenu='javascript:alert(${var1});return false;'>${var2}</div>`;
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert your string to **Template literal** with use of backticks( ` symbol)

```js
document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = `<div oncontextmenu='javascript:alert(` + var1 + `);return false;'>` + var2 + `</div>`;
```